# calculate minimum of max value of set of numbers

Tags: education, median

Suppose to have a set of numbers:

$$S:=\{ 1,2,3,9,10,56,58,60\}$$

How can i group this number like this:

group 1:$\{1,2,3,9,10\}$

group 2:$\{56,58,60\}$

and then take "56" as minimum value of group with highest value?

thanks ;-)

Comment: Am I missing something in the problem? Can you make it more general so that it is a little clearer what you are asking? In its current state, you have already solved the problem.

Comment: my question is how can i calculate this result. Is there an math algoritm to solve this? thank you!

Comment: Are the sets always split so that $x\in S_1$ and $y\in S_2$ implies $x<y$. That is, can a smaller number be mixed in with larger numbers?

Comment: @TerraHyde .... no. Numbers are group for dimension. A small value stay in smaller group. For example: the set of number is: 0.15,0.18,1,2,3,5,11,12,13,14. The result is 11 because is the small value of max group of values -> group are: 1: 0.15,0.18 --- 2: 1,2,3,5 --- 3: 11,12,13,14. Thanks!!

Comment: Hopefully the last question: I noticed that the sets are of variable length (one of them has $2$, while the others have $4$ elements in the last example). What exactly determines the places where the sets are split?

Comment: you're using vague terms. what is dimension for a set of scalars? what is value? is it a set average? do you always want two groups? specify your question better.

Comment: @TerraHyde the places is determinate only by difference from other values. Is a kind of cluster.

Comment: @kodlu the number of values in the set is variable. It can be 10 or 1000. The groups are variable too. to solve this calculation I think we should use an algorithm to cluster. ThankYou for your help!

Comment: But are you trying to split into exactly 2 groups? Also, define the "value" of a set. Do you want to maximize the difference between the maximum of one set (lower, with smaller numbers) and the minimum of the other (upper)? Or maximize the difference between the averages of the numbers in the two sets?

Comment: @kodlu the number of groups is variable. Example set: 1,2,3, 21,22,23, 65,66,67, 100,101,102,103 --> grouped like this: {1,2,3}  {21,22,23} {65,66,67} {100,101,102,103} --> result "100". They are grouped by a kind of density through the difference to each other. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't, to my knowledge, a simple "do this thing and get the answer" kind of algorithm for this problem, but there are some algorithms capable of splitting up the set to be **mostly** "well-divided" into sort of sensible groups.

---

If the set has not repeats, there is a good method for sorting based on linear differences, but it relies heavily on the data already being sort of bunched together. It works kind of like this:

1. Sort your list from least to greatest
2. Take the first differences $x_{i+1}-x_i=\delta_i$
3. Take the second differences $\delta_{i+1}-\delta_i=\delta^*_i$
4. Find $i$ such that $|\delta^*_i|>|\delta^*_j|$ for $j\neq i$.
5. If $|\delta_i|\geq|\delta_{i+1}|$, split the set into $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that $x_j\in S_1$ for $j\leq i+1$. Otherwise, split it so that $x_j\in S_1$ for $j\leq i$.
6. Repeat until the desired "clustering" is achieved.

---

Another algorithm exists that relies heavily on order of magnitude. For strictly positive data, the algorithm works kind of like this:

1. Take the natural logarithm of each $x_i$ to get $m_i=\ln(x_i)$
2. If $\lfloor y_i\rfloor=\lfloor y_j\rfloor$, then $y_i$ and $y_j$ go in the same subset.
3. If higher similarity is desired, split each subset using $ky_i$ for some constant $k>1$
4. If lower similarity is allowed, split on $ky_i$ for $0<k<1$
5. Run steps 1 and 2 with several values of $k$ to find "optimal" arrangement

---

Finally, you **could** extend the second method by taking $z_i=\ln|x_i|$ and clustering these, which would allow negative values. This also requires an added rule: if $x_i$ and $x_j$ have different signs, they go in different sets.

---

Once you have the subsets divided up, the process for finding the desired value is REALLY simple:

1. Find the minimum value in each set.
2. Find the maximum among these values.

Comment: it's a good point to start! thank you!